# Install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu not working

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu installed on my NVMe drive on my computer. I wanted to install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu. I followed tutorials and when I boot from the USB stick which has Windows 10 on it and go through the steps I cannot install it on the disk which has Ubuntu installed as it gives an error although in the tutorials I saw online it worked fine. Here is the error that appears:
[image]

I went into the installation log file and I cannot know what is causing the issue, here is the contents of the [log file](https://pasteall.org/ay9p)

Answer (score 0):

the most compatible way is to have windows first on the drive (really) then install Linux distro. If you do find a way to do that i think there is.   You may have to re burn 10 if you cant do it the other way, I think you had too prepare Grub by going into its configuration file make changes / then make more changes, it is a hassle. check the setup files for clues to an easier way  Gl.

U can read the setup files view the logs on a computer that does not include the corresponding kit, you must run a script from the root of the media that installs the Event Trace for Windows (ETW) provider. From the command line, type:

" Cscript D:\sources\etwproviders\etwproviderinstall.vbs install D:\sources\etwproviders  "
the D: is in example DVD but whatever you tried to install 10 with use that letter or whatever

Comment: So what are the steps to install windows first? Do I have to delete the drive in the step shown in my screenshot then install windows in it then install ubuntu after that?

Answer (score 0):

You must install to your usb of the type GPT or MBR.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re saying.  Can you clarify? … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compress volume disc  like this
[image]

than you have not active this disc

Comment: Please edit your post to include some explanation on why you think disk compression will solve the OP's problem.